# Counting occurrence of a word in LISP lists

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

So I have to count the occurrence of a word(or character, to be more specific) in a list in lisp. For example, the input:

```
(freq  'c '(a c c c c (c c c e)))
```

should produce a count of 7, since there are 7 c's in the list argument. The code I have is the following but it does not work. I can count the 4 c's that are base elements and the 3 c's that are in the sublist, but I dont know how to add them together. Also, I'm using only primitive data types.

```
(defun freq (a L)
    (cond
        ((null L) 0)
        ((listp (car L)) ( (freq a (car L))) ((freq a (cdr L))))
        ((eq a (car L))(+ 1 (freq a (cdr L))))
        (t ((freq a (cdr L))))))
```

Comment: in your second `cond` condition, shouldn't those recursive calls be added

Comment: how do I add recursive calls? Sorry for the elementary question, but I'm pretty much self teaching from the ground up here..Like, I'm not assigning any variables so how would I write the mathematical expression for such addition?

Comment: it's just `(+ <call1> <call2>)`

Comment: So I would put a second cond condition(since I only have one in my original code) and do a (+ <call1> <call2>) command?

Comment: no, I meant the second conditional branch in your `cond` -- `((listp (car L)) (+ (freq ..) (freq ...)))`

Comment: Ahhh I got it. I didn't know I could do that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a character then it's should be written with this prefix -> #\
and the sequence would be a string so there is no need recursion here.

```
(count #\c "(a c c c c (c c c e))") => 7
```

What you're dealing with in your example is symbol (with a single quote) through a list which contains other symbols or cons. So if you need to count all the same symbol you could write something like that  :

```
(defparameter *nb* 0)

(defun look-deeper (test seq)
    (loop for i in seq do
          (compare test i)))

(defun compare (test item)
  (let ((type (type-of item)))
    (case type
      (symbol (when (eql test item) (incf *nb*)))
      (cons   (look-deeper test item)))))

(look-deeper 'c '(a c c c c (c c c e))) => NIL
*nb* => 7
```

Or something better..

Answer (score 0):

```
 (defun count-occurences (obj lst)
   (let ((acc 0))
   (labels ((test (obj-2)
          (eq obj obj-2)))
     (dolist (x lst)
       (if (consp x)
       (let ((sample (remove-if-not #'test x)))
         (if sample
         (incf acc (length sample))))
       (if (eq x obj)
           (incf acc 1)))))
   acc))
```

We could create a function that takes an obj to test and a lst as the argument and create a local accumulator to keep track of how many times the obj occurs in the list. Then we could create a local function that tests to see if the obj we pass to it is eq to the obj passed as an argument to the global function (also note that if you are working with strings you might want to use string-equal or equal because eq will not work since they are not the same object, but eq will work with symbols which you used in your example). We can then iterate through the list, and if the element in the list is a cons we can use remove-if-not to remove any element that doesn't pass our test (is not eq to the obj), and based on the length of the list increment our accumulator accordingly. If it is not a cons and is eq to our obj we will also increment the accumulator, then we can return the value of our accumulator.

And if we test it:

```
CL-USER> (count-occurences 'c '(a c c c c (c c c)))
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is actually correct, there are just some small mis-parenthesis problems in your code. The only change you need for your code to work is to change you `listp` and `t` clauses from

```
((listp (car L)) ( (freq a (car L))) ((freq a (cdr L))))
```

into

```
((listp (car L)) (+ (freq a (car L)) (freq a (cdr L))))
```

and from

```
 (t ((freq a (cdr L))))
```

into

```
(t (freq a (cdr L)))
```

Then evaluating your function works just as you expect:

```
 (defun freq (a L)
    (cond
        ((null L) 0)
        ((listp (car L)) (+ (freq a (car L)) (freq a (cdr L))))
        ((eq a (car L))(+ 1 (freq a (cdr L))))
        (t (freq a (cdr L)))))


(freq  'c '((a (c f c)) c c c (c c (d c f (c 8 c) c) e))) ; => 11 (4 bits, #xB, #o13, #b1011)
```